# Range Reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am testing some VBA code. In spreadsheet, I defined a range as "Test_Range_1", which include 10 cells in a column and have A, B, B, C, C, C, D, D, D, D. Then running VBA as below, I will see a message box showing A.

```
Sub Range_Test()
    MsgBox (Range("Test_Range_1")(1))
End Sub
```

My questions are as below:

1. If I modify the code as `MsgBox (Range("Test_Range_1")(0))`, then the message box will show blank. However, as I understand, range/array index always starts from 0. How come in this case, reference to 0 will give me blank?
2. If I modify the code as below, i.e., set `Rng` to be the same range as in spreadsheet first, then it will give me error saying subscript out of range. I don't know why the previous code works but this doesn't. Looks like the same in essence to me. Why?

   `Sub Range_Test() Rng = Range("Test_Range_1") MsgBox Rng(1)  End Sub`

Comment: Where did you find that a range object starts from index 0? It starts from a top-left cell AFAIK which is `(1,1)`. In fact, for me your code errors out. Note that in your 2nd code, you don't actually `Set` a range object, just a variant array of values.

Comment: @JvdV I can see here saying "By default, an array is indexed beginning with zero, so the upper bound of the array is 364 rather than 365.". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays

Comment: Array <> Range of cells. Don't assume they are the same.

Comment: How many cells does "Test_Range_1" named range, contain?

Comment: @JvdV What is the difference between these two?
`MsgBox (Range("Test_Range_1")(1))` and 'Rng = Range("Test_Range_1")     MsgBox Rng(1, 1)` In the first one, I can just use (1); but in the second one, I need to use (1, 1)?

Comment: @FaneDuru As in my question, 10 cells in a column/vertically, A, B, B, C, C, C, D, D, D, D.

Comment: Your way of 'building' a range is a little strange for me... But, I can understand that it has 10 cells, and the enumeration you show represents the values of the respective cells. Is that correct? The normal way would be to show the range address. Something like "A2:A11"... Anyhow, the answer to your question in the above comment would be: 1. `MsgBox Range("Test_Range_1")(1)` returns **the first cell of the range**. 2.  `MsgBox Rng(1, 1)` returns the same, but more accurate. It returns the first cell **in the range first column`...

Comment: A range can have more columns. For instance, if `rng` has "A2:C4" address, it contains 3 columns and three rows. To return the second element of the third row you should use `rng(2,3)`... It would be the same with `rng(4)`, but less eloquent. Excel counts the range cells from top left to the right, then down and so on... Then, in Excel are zero based only 1D arrays (without columns...). Even for 'solving' this aspect in a unitary way, you can use `Option Base 1` on top of the module and it will also be 1 based.

Comment: But you need to know that a `Range` needs to be set! `set rng = Range("Test_Range_1")`. If you do not declare it and use `Rng = Range("Test_Range_1")`, VBA guesses that you need an array, which usually is obtained using `Rng = Range("Test_Range_1").value`... Always base 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a)** Arrays in VBA can start at any index.

```
Dim a(1 to 10)   ' Array with 10 elements from 1 to 10
Dim b(0 to 9)    ' Array with 10 elements from 0 to 9
Dim c(-4 to 5)   ' Array with 10 elements from -4 to 5
```

If you don't specify the lower index, it will be 0 - except if you use [`Option Base 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement)

```
Dim d(10)        ' Array with either 10 or 11 elements
```

**b)** `Range("Test_Range_1")` is a Range, not an array. You can access the cells of a Range by either a single index (that start at 1) or by row and column index.

```
MsgBox Range("Test_Range_1")(1) 
MsgBox Range("Test_Range_1")(1, 1)
```

will fetch the first cell of the Range. As `Value` is the default property, the message box displays the content of the cell.

When you use the syntax with only 1 parameter, you can access the cell to the left of the range with index 0. If you use 2 parameters (row, col), you can even access more cells to the left/top, eg with `Range("Test_Range_1")(-1, -1)`, assuming that those cell exists. (Don't do this, it is really confusing).

**c)** With

```
Rng = Range("Test_Range_1")
```

You will write a 2-dimensional array of values to `Rng` - no matter if the Range has only one row or column. Both indexes starts at 1, no matter what `Option Base` you are using.
Only exception is if the range contains only one cell, then `Rng` will get the value of the cell.

To get a value from `Rng`, you will need to specify both indexes, like

```
MsgBox Rng(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object is quite different to an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays) object. Note that you can have multidimensional arrays which could be the cause of confusion for you here?

The official documentation about range object is quite clear:

> *"The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to the
> Value property and calls with parameters to the Item member.
> Accordingly, someRange = someOtherRange is equivalent to
> someRange.Value = someOtherRange.Value, someRange(1) to
> someRange.Item(1) and someRange(1,1) to someRange.Item(1,1)"*

The 1st item in a range object is the top-left cell. The index for both row/column starts at 1, not zero. Therefor your 1st code will error out when your range starts at `A1`. If not, then as per @[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory) then index works as an offset to the range object. In your case I suppose you have an empty cell straight above your range object. Your 2nd piece of code loads your values (default) in a [variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type) variable containing a 2D reference of your range object. Therefor, this code will error out because you need to reference both row/column index.

If your goal is to load the actuall range into a variable then `Set` an actual range variable using:

```
Sub Range_Test()

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("Test_Range_1")

Debug.Print rng(1)
Debug.Print rng(1, 1)
Debug.Print rng.Item(1)
Debug.Print rng.Item(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: The first code will only error if there are no cells above the specified range. You can use 0 and negative numbers to return cells above/to the left of specified ranges. For example: `Range("A4")(-1).address` will return $A$2. It works like `Offset` but offset by 1 ;)

Comment: I'll edit that in. New information for me too ;) @Rory. Thanks